# Existence of Fixed Point in Proof of Second Sylow Theorem

Tags: group-theory

I was reading this proof of the Second Sylow Theorem: https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Sylow_implies_order-dominating. And I didn't fully understand how the author proved that a fixed point exists. If Q has cardinality $p^{\beta}$ and the left coset space of P has cardinality $m$, then couldn't it be possible that $p^{\beta} < m$, then the action of Q on any particular coset of P can map that coset to $p^{\beta}$ other cosets but not the same one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So more generally: assume that $G$ is a $p$-group that acts on $X$ such that $p$ does not divide $|X|$.

Assume that $x\in X$ **is not** a fixed point. It follows that the subgroup $G_x=\{g\in G\ |\ gx=x\}$ **is proper**. Recall that $Gx\simeq G/G_x$ where $Gx=\{gx\ |\ g\in G\}$ is the orbit of $x$. Since $G$ is a $p$-group then it follows that $p$ divides $|Gx|$.

Now assume that there are no fixed points. Then $p$ divides the size of every orbit. In particular $p$ divides $|X|$ because $X$ is a disjoint union of orbits. It's a contradiction.

Comment: Ahh, thank you!